# invalid initialization of non-const reference

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to reference to a class variable which is a vector and change value of the vector. I got this error. what am I doing wrong? thanks in advance. ( "pick" is just an int. )

```
 class tic
{
private:
vector<int> move;   //calculate moves
vector<int> value1; //player1's points
vector<int> value2; //player2's points
vector<int> value;  //exchange value
vector<string> board;   //numbers on the board
public:
void setboard ();   //output numbers on the board
void setvalue();    //each number's value corresponding to the numbers on the board
void setvalue12();  //values of player1 and playe2
void set(); //setboard, setvalue, setvalue12
void printboard (int &pick); //print board
int pick(int &m);       //pick a number on the board
bool sum15 (vector<int> &sum15);  //check if sum is 15 of any combination of 3
int WinLoseDraw (int &pick, int player);    //win=0, continue=1, draw=20
void WLD(int &player)
{   
    vector<int> &temp=(player==1)?this->value1:this->value2;
    temp[pick-1]=value[pick-1]; //input values
    if (sum15(temp))    //if any sum of 3 is 15
    {
        cout<<"WINS!"<<endl;
    }
}

};
```

this is the original codes. I am trying to simply this part with a member function or an inline function named WLD

```
    if (player==1)  
    {       
        value1[pick-1]=value[pick-1];   //input values

        if (sum15(this->value1))    //if any sum of 3 is 15
            {
                cout<<"PLAYER1 WINS!"<<endl;
                return 0;
            }
    }
    else  
    {
        value2[pick-1]=value[pick-1];

        if (sum15(this->value2))
        {
            cout<<"PLAYER2 WINS!"<<endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

with the updated codes. I got erros on "temp[pick-1]=value[pick-1];

```
tic.h: In member function ‘void tic::WLD(int&)’:
tic.h:28: error: invalid use of member (did you forget the ‘&’ ?)
tic.h:28: error: invalid use of member (did you forget the ‘&’ ?)
```

Comment: Why you defined a reference to that `vector`?

Comment: hi I just updated codes. just want to simplify the original codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reference is not assignable, only constructible. You could try doing:

```
vector<int>& temp = ( player == 1 ) ? this->value1 : this->value2;
```

**Update:**

With the updated code, all you have to do is drop the `const` in `temp` to make it work. Note that you have *lvalues*, the *r* in *rvalues* comes not from *reference* but from *right*, as in usable on the right side of an expression.

Comment: Note that this only works if this->value1() and this->value2() return  lvalues, since you can't bind an rvalue to a non-const reference.

Comment: value1 and value2 store int numbers

Comment: then you'll have to make temp a real `vector<int>` instead of a reference, i.e. `vector<int> temp (( player == 1 ) ? this->value1() : this->value2());`. Note that doing this will cause the vector to be copied, but you can't avoid that if you want temp to be non-const and value1()/value2() return by value

Comment: error: no match for call to ‘(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >) ()’ I got this error for     vector<int> temp (( player == 1 ) ? this->value1() : this->value2())  and invalid use of member (did you forget the ‘&’ ?) for temp[pick-1]=value[pick-1]; @je4d

Comment: It would help if you could post the function prototypes / member declarations for `value1`,  `value2` and `value`... from that error it sounds like they're variables, not functions, so you'd need `vector<int> temp (( player == 1 ) ? this->value1 : this->value2)`

Comment: ok - so `value1` and `value2` are actually lvalues, so if you want to modify them in place then make temp a reference to one or the other with `vector<int> temp& (( player == 1 ) ? this->value1 : this->value2)`

Comment: vector<int> temp& (( player == 1 ) ? this->value1 : this->value2)   no "="?  temp[pick-1]=value[pick-1]; this line gives me tic.h:28: error: invalid use of member (did you forget the ‘&’ ?)  btw, how do I highlight the codes? @je4d

Comment: type var (initial value) is almost equivalent to type var = intial value, the difference isn't important here. use backticks for the code. I can't immediately see why you're getting "invalid use of member", but i've just started an episode of House.. so back in ~40 minutes

Comment: ah, the invalid use of member is because pick is a function and you're using it as a value.

Comment: thanks @je4d. palmhead myself.  I got an error on the line underneath. error codes are posted.

Comment: The code in the question is still using it as a value when it's a function.. and you can't simply replace it with pick() because pick takes an argument. This is a bit off topic now, you should probably post it as a new question if it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is in the `vector<int> &temp=vector<int>()` line.  Its not really clear what you're doing here however, since you attempt to assign `&temp` and then immediately reassign it in the branches of the if-else statement.

Comment: what I am trying to do is to assign either this->value1 or this-value2 to a temp variable. if n==1, then temp = this->value1. else temp= this->value2. and change the values of either value1 or value2 using temp.

Comment: If `this->value1` and `this->value2` are already vectors, and you want a reference to one of them to use later, then k-ballo's answer above should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A reference cannot be reassigned, you are declaring it and then in your `if` setting it to a new value.

I don't think you should be trying to use a reference in this case.

Comment: @ihm - You have to assign a reference when it is declared. After that you cannot reseat the reference to another object (http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/references.html#faq-8.5). Have a look at K-ballo's answer, that's probably the easiest fix for your code at the moment without having to restructure it. Although I'd recommend you think about the code structure, why are you storing a player's score separately, why not have a `Player` object with the vector inside it?

Comment: thanks a lot. I understand it now. what should I use in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Once a reference is initialised it cannot be re-initialised or assigned.

It looks like you are trying to do this, using [the ternary (or conditional) operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/):

```
const vector<int>& values = (player == 1) ? value1 : value2;
```

---

You say:

> ( "pick" is just an int. )

Your code says:

```
int pick(int &m);
```

`pick` here is a *method*, not an `int`.

If you are compiling with `g++`, I recommend enabling (at least) `-Wshadow`, which will warn when you make this kind of mistake. You've done the same thing with `sum15`.

Comment: it gives me this error with the codes above.    tic.h: In member function ‘void tic::WLD(int&)’:
tic.h:27: error: no match for call to ‘(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >) ()’
tic.h:27: error: no match for call to ‘(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >) ()’
tic.h:28: error: invalid use of member (did you forget the ‘&’ ?)
tic.h:28: error: invalid use of member (did you forget the ‘&’ ?)
tic.h:29: error: no matching function for call to ‘tic::sum15(const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)’
tic.h:23: note: candidates are: bool tic::sum15(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)

Comment: You have two problems here. 1: You have too many identifiers called `pick`. 2: `sum15()` takes a non-`const` reference when it can probably take a `const` reference.

Comment: thanks, john. I am changing them. do you have AIM, google chat or something else?

Comment: @ihm: I don't run a private consultancy service. Perhaps I should :-)